# How to use typescript 2.1 in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript2.1

We are working on a web project in which we are using typescript 2.1 . **I have visual studio 2013 on my system which has typescript 1.8**. It gives compile time error when project is opened with visual studio 2013 but it compile and run perfectly with visual studio 2015(which has typescript 2.1) on another machine.

**How can I install typescript 2.1 in visual studio 2013**.